# How does the superimum of lower sums of partitions work?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, supremum-and-infimum

The definition of integral defines lower integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$, $\underline{I}_a^b (f)$, as the supremum of the lower sums of all partitions. But isn't the lower value of $f(x)$  infimum? how does this definition work?

Comment: It might help if you explained what you mean by "isn't the lower value of $f(x)$ infimum?" In a Riemann lower sum, the lowest value of $f(x)$ appears multiplied by the length of an interval which contains the $x$ at which that lowest value is achieved.  The sum can thus be a lot higher than the lowest value of $f(x)$ if the function takes on higher values in other intervals.

Comment: The criteria "the lowest highest point (inf of the sups)" and "the highest lowest point (sup of the infs)" select different US states. (Replace with whatever geographic region is most compelling.) I leave to you the pleasant exercise of pondering how this relates to Riemann integrability.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of "minimax" or "maximin": you have a function of two variables*. Taking the min (resp. max) in one variable gives a function of one variable. You then take the max (resp. min) in that variable and you wind up with a number. This is a fairly common notion.

It's the right thing to do in integration because you can imagine drawing the step function which corresponds to the lower sum of your function with a particular partition. When you refine the partition, part of the step function *increases*, getting closer to the actual graph in the process. The *supremum* operation in your definition is responsible for this "increasing" effect.

* It's not *exactly* a function of two variables in integration: the minimum is taken over evaluation points, while the maximum is taken over partitions. But the evaluation points are not independent of the partition. Still, this is the idea.